# Simple Meteor http call timing out

Tags: json, http, meteor

I wish to get some currency prices from a web service which provides them in JSON format.

Here is the code I am using with the simple example (hello world) -

```
  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.hello.greeting = function () {
     return "Welcome to webserve.";
     };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
        Meteor.call('getprice');
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });

  Meteor.methods({
  getprice: function() {
    console.log('On the server');
    var url = "http://quotes.instaforex.com/get_quotes.php?m=json&q=AUDUSD";
    //var url ="http://www.google.com";

    HTTP.get(url, function(error, result) {
    if(!error) {
        console.log(result.content);
        }
    else console.log(error);
    }); 
  }
 }); 

}
```

When I run the app, and click the button in the client, i get a timeout message on the server.
Notice the url - If I copy/paste it in a browser I receive the right json,
Cross Domain policy does not apply because the code is on server side.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried with a fresh meteor project (with the `http` package) using your code and it works fine. hope you're short aud.

Comment: Copying into a fresh meteor project on a Nitrous.io box worked like a charm, but running it from my windows machine its timing out... might have to do something with my corp firewall

Answer (score 0):

Copying into a new project helped, no change required.